# How to get Roles from UserPrincipal in Java?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, userprincipal

I created a class(Named as **CustomRequestWrapper**) which is implementing **HttpServletRequestWrapper** .In **CustomRequestWrapper** class i am setting user principal.Now in my code i want to get list of roles from the user principal.I tried to use GenericPrincipal Class from **tomcat-catalina** jar but i am getting casting exception **CustomRequestWrapper** cannot be cast to **GenericPrincipal**. Could any one have idea how to get roles from user principal?

Note: I am using Apache Tomcat Server

Here's my code:

```
public class CustomRequestWrapper extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper {

public CustomRequestWrapper(String User,List<String> roles,HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    this.user=User;
    this.roles=roles;
    this.realRequest=request;
    headerMap = new HashMap();
}
String user;  
List<String> roles = null; 
HttpServletRequest realRequest;  
private Map headerMap;

public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
    headerMap.put(name, new String(value));
}

public Enumeration getHeaderNames() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getRequest();
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for (Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        list.add(e.nextElement().toString());
    }

    for (Iterator i = headerMap.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        list.add(i.next());
    }
    return Collections.enumeration(list);
}

public String getHeader(String name) {
    Object value;
    if ((value = headerMap.get("" + name)) != null)
        return value.toString();
    else
        return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(name);
}
     @override
public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {  
    if (roles == null) {  
        return this.realRequest.isUserInRole(role);  
    }  
    return roles.contains(role);  
}  

@override
public Principal getUserPrincipal() {  
    if (this.user == null) {  
        return realRequest.getUserPrincipal();  
    }  

    // make an anonymous implementation to just return our user  
    return new Principal() {  

        public String getName() {       
            return user;  
        }  
    };  
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to get the roles for a tomcat authenticated user, that is the roles declared in tomcat-users.xml ?

Comment: No .I am trying to get the roles for my app authenticated user

Comment: Fine, could you show the code for you `CustomRequestWrapper` ?

Comment: Please check it ,i uploaded my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code, you inject the username and the roles into your `CustomRequestWrapper` in constructor. As you have overriden `getUserPrincipal` in `CustomRequestWrapper` it returns no longer a tomcat `GenericPrincipal` but your anonymous class that only knows to return the name of the user you gave, this via `getName()`. You should try to return a tomcat `GenericPrincipal` through

```
  @Override
  public Principal getUserPrincipal()
  {
    if (this.user == null)
    {
      return realRequest.getUserPrincipal();
    }

    // return a forged GenericPrincipal
    return new GenericPrincipal(user, "", roles);
  }
```

Alternatively, you could create a custom implementation of Principal knowing about roles.

That will only work if you successfully inject your user and its roles at `CustomRequestWrapper` construction.

Comment: It works fine for me.I am extremely sorry i am not eligible to vote up or else i could have voted you

Answer (score 2):

The exception you mentioned may be the key to solve your issue

```
CustomRequestWrapper cannot be cast to GenericPrincipal
```

You have to cast the `Principal` object and not the `CustomRequestWrapper`. Here is a sample method that you can add under your `CustomRequestWrapper` class and which should return the list of user roles under Tomcat AS. (I assume that this is a messy method):

```
private String[] getRolePrincipal() {
  final GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = (GenericPrincipal) getUserPrincipal();
  return genericPrincipal.getRoles();
}
```

So the final `CustomRequestWrapper` will be as follows:

```
public class CustomRequestWrapper extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper
{

  public CustomRequestWrapper(String User, List<String> roles, HttpServletRequest request)
  {
    super(request);
    this.user = User;
    this.roles = roles;
    this.realRequest = request;
    headerMap = new HashMap();
  }

  String user;
  List<String> roles = null;
  HttpServletRequest realRequest;
  private Map headerMap;

  public void addHeader(String name, String value)
  {
    headerMap.put(name, new String(value));
  }

  public Enumeration getHeaderNames()
  {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getRequest();
    List list = new ArrayList();
    for (Enumeration e = request.getHeaderNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); )
    {
      list.add(e.nextElement().toString());
    }

    for (Iterator i = headerMap.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    {
      list.add(i.next());
    }
    return Collections.enumeration(list);
  }

  public String getHeader(String name)
  {
    Object value;
    if ((value = headerMap.get("" + name)) != null)
      return value.toString();
    else
      return ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeader(name);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isUserInRole(String role)
  {
    if (roles == null)
    {
      return this.realRequest.isUserInRole(role);
    }
    return roles.contains(role);
  }

  @Override
  public Principal getUserPrincipal()
  {
    if (this.user == null)
    {
      return realRequest.getUserPrincipal();
    }

    // make an anonymous implementation to just return our user
    return new Principal()
    {

      public String getName()
      {
        return user;
      }
    };
  }

  public String[] getRolePrincipal() {
    final GenericPrincipal genericPrincipal = (GenericPrincipal) getUserPrincipal();
    return genericPrincipal.getRoles();
  }
}
```